# Use a single Ethernet cable to connect multiple devices

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cable

So, here is some backstory.

The router is in my bed room and somehow i want to bring an ethernet cable to the living room by passing it through the concrete wall. Since the walls are concrete i cannot make any modifications and my only option is to use the telephone line which is basically an existing cable the passes through the walls in a tiny tube.

The line that im going to use used to be the old telephone cable line that is not needed anymore giving me to opportunity to replace the cable with an ethernet cable. Since i can only pass 1 cable through that line i can only have a single line from the living room terminating in to my bed room. Normally that wouldn't be an issue since it achieves exactly what i want, however it bothers me that no other room can benefit from my upgrade.

Ideally i would be able to give an ethernet connection to all possible rooms however im not sure how i can achieve that by having a single cable.

The setup:

**Bed Room 1**

1. Has the router
2. Has the terminating outlet

**Bed Room 2**

1. Has an outlet

**Living room**

1. Has an other router that acts as a WiFi spot

Since all 3 rooms will share a single cable how can i connect devices on them?

If lets say room 2 and the living room have a device on them wouldn't the signal be mixed?

Comment: You can use a switch, but you already have a router, so that’s counter productive.  Go wireless or use a PowerLine adapter.   You would have to connect both outlets to the router to accomplish what you want.  You would have to rewire the entire house to accomplish what you want

Comment: If there is a splice at one of the terminations then you technically have two different cables.  It might have came off the same roll but after it was cut it became two.

Comment: How big a cable can you pass through the tube? I'm wondering if it would be viable to pass a thicker cable with more pairs in it, then separate them into multiple pairs.

Answer (score 6):

Just put a cheap ethernet switch in your living room, connect more cables to it, and connect as many other devices or more switches to the cables as you want.

The signal won't be "mixed", because each end device has an ethernet address (also called "MAC address"), so each device will only react to packets addressed to it. However, they will all share the bandwidth of the single cable from living room to bedroom. This is normally not an issue, because LAN bandwidth is much higher than achievable internet bandwidth.

Don't follow the recommendation in the comment and go wireless or use a powerline adapter if you can use ethernet cables. Ethernet cables are superior to both alternatives, especially over longer distances.